# How to reduce and filter arrays in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

So I want to filter my array  as followed:

Lets say my `array1 = ['c', 'd']`

My data array =

```
[{
    "userid": "a",
    "age": 19,
    "name": "john"
}, {
    "userid": "c",
    "age": 119,
    "name": "joy"
}, {
    "userid": "d",
    "age": 119,
    "name": "jesse"
}]
```

I want to filter out my data array so that only those objects in data array are  there whose userid values are present in array1.

Expected result:

```
new data array = [{
    "userid": "c",
    "age": 119,
    "name": "joy"
}, {
    "userid": "d",
    "age": 119,
    "name": "jesse"
}]
```

Comment: Use [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) [`arr.filter(e => array1.includes(e.userid));`](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/neu1o6ws/)

Comment: You can use the [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function of an array to filter an array. Closures will do the rest.

Comment: Getting error TypeError: array1.includes is not a function @Tushar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make you understand better, adding Tushar's solution without lambda expression,

```
newDataArray = dataArray.filter(function(item) {return array1.includes(item.userid)})
```

In ES5:

```
var newDataArray = dataArray.filter(function (item) {
    return array1.indexOf(item.userid) !== -1;
});
```

Comment: Getting error TypeError: array1.includes is not a function

Comment: Thanks done can u please explain why the first soln dint work?

Comment: @mohd.gadi https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes ...   check browser compatibility

Answer (score 0):

```js
var a1 = [
    {
        "userid": "a",
        "age": 19,
        "name": "john"
    },
    {
        "userid": "c",
        "age": 119,
        "name": "joy"
    },
    {
        "userid": "d",
        "age": 119,
        "name": "jesse"
    }
];

var a2 = ['c','d'];


var newObj = [];

a1.filter(function(object,index){
    var x = object.userid;
    a2.filter(function(userId){
    if(x==userId){
      newObj[index-1] = object;
    }  
   });
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(newObj));
```